# Change month names php gantti class

Tags: php

For a project I use the php gantti class from: https://github.com/bastianallgeier/gantti
This works perfectly. 
What does not succeed, however, is converting the English month names to Dutch names. So instead of May it should be Mei. 
I can not find the setting that determines the month names. 
I have tried this: date_default_timezone_set ('Europe / Amsterdam'); setlocale (LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
That does not work, however. 
Is it possible to adjust the month names?

Kind regards, Rutger

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) to format date into format and timezone:

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'de_DE',
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
    "Europe/Amsterdam"
);
$fmt->setPattern('MMMM'); // set format of output.

echo $fmt->format( strtotime("20.05.2018") ); // here you set date, you can use time() instead
// I put 20.05 to test 'Mai' month.

// Mai
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick response. 
I get the following error message: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found. 
In the php.ini file I have changed the following line from:
; extension = php_intl.dll 
in: 
extension = php_intl.dll
But this does not help. 
what am I doing wrong?
I like to hear it, thanks!

Comment: @Rutger, it looks well, have you restarted apache server after changing php.ini? also you can check php.ini by `phpinfo();` command (make sure of right path to php.ini)